# What is the formula used to display energy markers on HUD?

Tags: aerodynamics, hud

I would like to know what is the formula used to display energy markers on the [head-up display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-up_display) (HUD) of fighter aircraft. Does it consist of [Mach number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_number) or TAS or CAS?

Comment: Can you please provide an example?  Any photos?

Comment: Perhaps you are asking for the [potential flight path angle](https://www.ecologie.gouv.fr/sites/default/files/head_up_display_symbology.pdf#page=55) (PFPA depicted by chevrons), derived from the total energy (sum of potential and kinetic energy)  or the velocity vector FPM/FPV depicted by a circle. Both are presented [here](https://www.eaa.org/-/media/files/news/ohio-university-energy-management-paper.ashx). A [view of the symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcJpP.png) on a PFD. They are used together: If the chevrons are above the velocity vector, the aircraft is accelerating.